# Can't connect to rumpus server via local IP on macbook pro

Tags: macos, ip, localhost

Today I wake up and my MacBook pro can no longer connect to my Rumpus server via the internal IP address.

Every other machine in the house can connect to the server GI n the browser via the SSL/HTTPS:// layer at this address:

```
https://192.168.1.101
```

and until today. My MacBook pro just won't open it in any browser. In chrome I get

```
**Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**
```

Now I know it must be my macbook pro because everything else can still connect.
What I don't know is what has changed in my setup for it to not be receiving any signals from the server anymore.
I don't think I installed anything that would have changed the settings to do this.

I've checked my host file and it is default so it should all be in order

Also, I can connect to the external dns for the server eg. MYSERVER.zapto.org when not connected to the internal network of course. Just as soon as I head for the local ip and I'm connected to the same network as the server, I just hit a brick wall.

If anybody knows what preferences or problems could be causing this issue and can give me a bit of help I would be greatly appreciative.

EDIT:

I've re-installed OSx10.8.5 and it's still not working. It works on every machine except my personal one. It's making me crazy.

No matter what I try, it just won't connect to the server. It won't ping, it won't do anything from this machine.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was a slightly embarrassing but simple answer to this.

I had managed to blacklist the ip of my MacBook by messing around with accounts too much and presto locked me out.

Moral is don't put your password In too many times wrong if you have guess protection on in rumpus.

You will have to go and delete yourself from the blocked ip s